# How to add multiple Inputs from the same loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing an exercise with python for a course I am currently enrolled in, but I cannot figure out how to add multiple inputs from the same loop together, here is the code I have so far:

```
ClassesTaken = input ("How many Classes are you taking?")
Class_Amount = int(ClassesTaken)
for i in range (Class_Amount):
    print("Class", i+1)
    Credits = int(input("How many credits for this class?"))
    total = 0
    total += Credits
print(total)
```

I am trying to add the inputs within the for loop

Comment: Move `total = 0` outside the `for` loop (above), since you re-assign it to `0` on every iteration.

Comment: It's recommended to use conventional variable names. These types of variables should all be lowercase with words separated by underscores. It makes the code easier to read, especially when you get deeper into the language. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `total = 0` outside your `for` loop, as this is re-assigning a value of `0` on every iteration. Thus, you are currently only printing the last number of credits entered by the user.

Your code should therefore look like:

```
ClassesTaken = input ("How many Classes are you taking?")
Class_Amount = int(ClassesTaken)
total = 0
for i in range (Class_Amount):
    print("Class", i+1)
    Credits = int(input("How many credits for this class?"))
    total += Credits
print(total)
```

Example input and output:

```
How many Classes are you taking?2
Class 1
How many credits for this class?10
Class 2
How many credits for this class?12
22
```